# How do I disable scrolling in Safari without breaking the site?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, safari, stylus

I have a site and when I open popup, scrolling is blocked by assigning `body` property `overflow: hidden`. On all browsers all works well, there is a background blur, but in safari for some reason when you open popup shows the site blurred in the background, but after a second there is a white solid background. If you remove the task `overflow` then all works fine. I tried to set the `min-height` and `height` for `body`, but did not help.

[Here](https://profit4people.dezitech.studio) is the site where this is the problem. Popup by clicking on the button in the block "Create your own poll", "Earn money by completing polls" (third slide) and "Share your professional..." (fifth slide).

Here's part of the code for the popup (using `stylus` preprocessor and `vue3`. The site is in `laravel`):

```
const { default: axios } = require('axios');
const { createApp } = require('vue');

const body = document.body;
const page = document.querySelector('.scroll-wrapper');



// VUE 3
let popup = createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            show: false,
            success: false,

            name: '',
            email: '',
            email_paypal: '',
            brief: '',

            variant: {},
            variants: {
                poll: {
                    type: 'poll',
                    title: 'Create your own poll',
                    textarea: true,
                    button: 'Try it now'
                },
                earn: {
                    type: 'earn',
                    title: 'Earn money by completing polls',
                    textarea: false,
                    button: 'Subscribe'
                },
                share: {
                    type: 'share',
                    title: 'Share your knowledge',
                    textarea: true,
                    button: 'Register'
                },
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        open(type) {
            body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
            page.style.filter = 'blur(25rem)';

            this.name = this.email = this.email_paypal = this.brief = '';

            this.variant = this.variants[type];
            this.show = true;
        },
        close() {
            body.style.overflow = 'auto';
            page.style.filter = 'blur(0rem)';

            this.show = false;
            this.success = false;
        },
        send() {
            document.body.style.cursor = "wait";

            let formData = new FormData();

            formData.append('name', this.name);
            formData.append('email', this.email);
            formData.append('email_paypal', this.email_paypal);
            formData.append('brief', this.brief);

            axios.post(URL + '/popup/' + this.variant.type, formData)
                .then(response => {
                    this.name = this.email = this.email_paypal = this.brief = '';
                    this.success = true;
                    
                    document.body.style.cursor = "unset";
                });
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        
    }
})
.mount('#popup');

window.openPopup = popup.open;


 //STYLUS
.popup
    opacity 0
    pointer-events none
    z-index 9999

    &.popup__show
        opacity 1
        pointer-events all

    position fixed
    top 0
    left 0
    right 0
    bottom 0
    overflow-y scroll

    width 100% !important

    background-color rgba(#fff, 0.1)

    display flex
    justify-content center
    align-items flex-start

    padding 30rem

    .popup__content
        z-index 99999
        width 560rem
        padding 40rem 60rem
        border-radius basic-radius
        background-color #fff
        box-shadow 0 9rem 36rem 3rem rgba(#000, 0.05)

        .popup__form
            display flex
            flex-direction column

            gap 30rem

            transition 0.2s opacity

            .popup__text
                display flex
                flex-direction column

                gap 24rem

                .popup__title
                    font-size 26rem
                    font-weight 700
                    line-height 1

                .popup__subtitle
                    font-size 16rem
                    font-weight 500

            .popup__inputs
                display flex
                flex-direction column

                gap 22rem

                .popup__textarea
                    .popup__textarea-counter
                        text-align right
                        font-size 14rem
                        color rgba(black, 0.5)

            &.popup__form_hide
                opacity 0
                pointer-events none



        position relative
        .popup__close
            position absolute
            top 30rem
            right 30rem

            width 30rem

            cursor pointer
            
            & > svg
                width 100%

        .popup__success
            pointer-events none
            opacity 0

            transition 0.2s opacity

            position absolute
            top 0
            left 0
            right 0
            bottom 0

            display flex
            flex-direction column
            justify-content center
            align-items center

            gap 45rem

            text-align: center

            .popup__success-image
                width 122rem

                & > svg
                    width 100%

            .popup__success-title
                width 70%

                font-size 36rem
                font-weight 700
                line-height 1.2

            &.popup__success_show
                opacity 1
                pointer-events unset

    .popup__bg
        position absolute
        top 0
        left 0
        right 0
        bottom 0

        z-index 0



@media all and (max-width tablet) // 800px
    .popup
        .popup__content
            .popup__form
                text-align left



@media all and (max-width mobile) // 500px
    .popup
        .popup__content
            padding 50rem 18rem

            .popup__form
                .popup__text
                    .popup__title
                        font-size 20rem

                    .popup__subtitle
                        font-size 14rem

                .input-text, .input-textarea
                    & > input, & > textarea, & > label
                        font-size 16rem
                        padding 12rem 18rem

            .popup__close
                top 18rem
                right 18rem

                width 25rem

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

 //HTML
<div id="popup">
    <div class="popup" :class="{ popup__show: show }">
        <div class="popup__content">
            <form method="POST" v-on:submit.prevent="send" class="popup__form" :class="{popup__form_hide: success}">
                <div class="popup__text">
                    <div class="popup__title">@{{ variant.title }}</div>
                    <div class="popup__subtitle">
                        Please leave your contacts and a brief explanation of your poll below.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="popup__inputs">
                    <x-input type="text" id="poll__name" name="name" placeholder="Name" vmodel="v-model=name" />
                    <x-input type="email" id="poll__email" name="email" placeholder="Email" vmodel="v-model=email" required />

                    <div v-if="variant.textarea" class="popup__textarea">
                        <x-input type="textarea" id="poll__brief" name="brief" placeholder="Describe your field and request for the survey" required minlength="100" maxlength="1000"  vmodel="v-model=brief" />
                        <div class="popup__textarea-counter">@{{ brief.length }}/1000</div>
                    </div>
                    <template v-else>
                        <x-input type="email" id="poll__email" name="paypal_email" placeholder="Your PayPal Email*" required vmodel="v-model=email_paypal" />
                    </template>
                </div>
                
                <button type="submit">@{{ variant.button }}</button>
            </form>

            <div class="popup__success" :class="{popup__success_show: success}">
                <div class="popup__success-image">
                    @svg('confetti')
                </div>
                <div class="popup__success-title">
                    Thank you! <br>We will contact you as soon as possible
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="popup__close" v-on:click="close">
                @svg('close')
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="popup__bg" v-on:click="close"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `I tried to set the min-height and height for body` ... did you try setting `max-height` ... the only one of three common height properties that could possibly limit the maximum height of the body

Comment: @Bravo I just tried this. It worked, but it takes the user to the top of the site instead of leaving him on the same block where he was